# Cabbage-hood meaning in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of cabbage-hood in the following sentence?

> When you can know the heady joy of mental action, why would you opt for a lobotomy, for voluntary cabbage-hood?

Comment: "Hood" here is in the same sense as in "motherhood" -- filling the role of a cabbage.

Comment: Probably also a play on cabbage-head.

Answer (score 2):

The 'hood' suffix means being in the state of or having the quality/condition/character of.

'Cabbage', in this case, almost definitely means dim-witted or stupid, referencing either the term cabbagehead (a thick-witted person) or the term "vegetable" for a brain-dead person, or both.

So, cabbage-hood would mean "the state of being extremely dim-witted or stupid"